# PostgreSQL range containment operator @> not working as expected for the upper boundary

Tags: postgresql, range

Postgres range datatype's "contains" operator is not working as I expect it. Can anyone help me to solve this

`select INT4RANGE(1,5) @> 5` giving `false` result, where it should be true because 5 in that range

Answer (score 2):

Ranges that don't specify if the bounds are inclusive or exclusive are created with [exclusive upper bound](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT)

> he two-argument form constructs a range in standard form (lower bound inclusive, upper bound exclusive)

So `int4range(1,5)` is the same as `int4range(1,5,'[)')` which excludes the value 5.

If you want the 5 to be included, create the range with an inclusive upper bound: `int4range(1,5,'[]')`

Comment: then its showing [1,6) in table

Comment: @DipanjanPanja: yes, all discrete ranges are normalized to a `[)` range. `[1,6)` is identical to `[1,5]`

Comment: so how can i get `int4range(1,5,'[)') @> 5` =  true, like is it possible with any other oparetor/query?

Comment: @DipanjanPanja: you can't. Because the range `int4range(1,5,'[)')` does **not** include the value 5. It's like asking "how can I make `5=6` result in `true`. You need `int4range(1,5,'[]')` which is identical to `int4range(1,6,'[)')`

Comment: @DipanjanPanja: That's not possible, the integer range [1,5) does not contain the integer 5. If you want to include the integer 5 as well, you need [1,5]

Comment: @DipanjanPanja maybe you are looking for such operators that return `true`. Is the first range strictly left of the second? `select INT4RANGE(1,5) << '[5,5]'::INT4RANGE` or Are the ranges adjacent? `select INT4RANGE(1,5) -|- '[5,5]'::INT4RANGE` [docu](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html)

Comment: for now i did that `select 5 between lower(INT4RANGE(1,5)) and upper(INT4RANGE(1,5));` its working fine.

Comment: Well, why not just use `int4range(1,5,'[]') @> 5`